# Dynamic Div Width affecting other Div width

Tags: javascript, css

How can the active change of an in-line div width affect the width of another in-line div?

```
<div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
</div>
```

Would javascript need to be used to resize both simultaneously? or is there a more elegant way with css?

I don't believe the css calc method can be used in this case?
width: calc(X-Y);

Example:

A similar concept would be the apple.com menu, where the expansion of the search box causes the change in div width of the menu tab item area. 
(apple uses a different method which I can't work out)

Answer (score 0):

It can be done using flexbox to fill the remaining width

```
display:flex
```

Answer (score 0):

The apple menu uses a container `ul` with `text-align: justify` and then adjusts the width of the search `li` when it is active.